# Configuring App Transport Security for WatchKit (LaunchServicesError error 0.)

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, nsapptransportsecurity

I am building a **WatchKit** app that talks to a *non*-HTTPS API, so I need to configure **App Transport Security** to allow for exception domains.

When I execute the `NSURLRequest`, I get the following error:

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

So I've added this to my Info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>domain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

But when I try to run in the Simulator, I get an Xcode error:

[image: The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to this is that you need to add the `NSAppTransportSecurity` keys to the `Info.plist` file for your Watch *Extension*, not your WatchKit App or iPhone App targets.

Comment: added mine to iphone app and watch extension, its useful in app if you have http calls in their too.